# anti-SMASH antismash --check-prereqs TRACEBACK and IMPORT ERRORS

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, biopython, gbk

I am now trying if my recently installed anti-SMASH would work. However, the following lines appear as I type `antismash --check-prereqs`:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/promt/asenv/bin/antismash", line 5, in 
> from antismash.**main** import entrypoint
> File "/home/promt/asenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/antismash/**init**.py", line 12, in 
> from antismash.main import run_antismash, get_detection_modules, 
> File "/home/promt/asenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/antismash/main.py", line 31, in 
> from antismash.common import logs, record_processing, serialiser
> File "/home/promt/asenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/antismash/common/record_processing.py", line 19, in 
> from antismash.common.secmet import Record
> File "/home/promt/asenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/antismash/common/secmet/**init**.py", line 11, in 
> from .record import Record
> File "/home/promt/asenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/antismash/common/secmet/record.py", line 25, in 
> from .features import (
> File "/home/promt/asenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/antismash/common/secmet/features/**init**.py", line 6, in 
> from .antismash_domain import AntismashDomain
> File "/home/promt/asenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/antismash/common/secmet/features/antismash_domain.py", line 10, in 
> from .domain import Domain, generate_protein_location_from_qualifiers
> File "/home/promt/asenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/antismash/common/secmet/features/domain.py", line 13, in 
> from .feature import Feature, FeatureLocation, Location
> File "/home/promt/asenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/antismash/common/secmet/features/feature.py", line 13, in 
> from antismash.common.secmet.locations import (
> File "/home/promt/asenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/antismash/common/secmet/locations.py", line 9, in 
> from Bio.SeqFeature import (
> ImportError: cannot import name 'AbstractPosition' from 'Bio.SeqFeature' (/home/promt/asenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Bio/SeqFeature.py)

How can I fix it? Thanks!

I also typed the following but to no avail:

```
antismash --help
antismash --help-showall
```

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'AbstractPosition' from 'Bio.SeqFeature' (/home/promt/asenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Bio/SeqFeature.py)

Comment: Look at Biopython code maybe now AbstractPosition is just Position or Location https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/SeqFeature.py